# Exception when exposing $window.print on angular scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm exposing $window.print() on scope like so:

```
$scope.print = $window.print;
```

However, this results in an exception:

> angular.js:13642 Exception message: Illegal invocation

I need to call print thru a separate function, like so to make it work:

```
$scope.print = printFn;
function printFn() { $window.print(); }
```

Any ideas why I can't use the first alternative?
Running Angular 1.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to assume that every object method depends on `this` unless proven otherwise, so method should be bound to its context before it is assigned as another object's method.

`window.print` is native method, in Chrome it just throws `Illegal invocation` instead of complaining on inappropriate `this` context.

Instead of wrapper function, it may be

```
$scope.print = $window.print.bind($window);
```

or

```
$scope.print = angular.bind($window, $window.print);
```